# Not sure whether the container is listed as [] in azure storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-storage-account

I am following (previous and) this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/connect-an-app-to-azure-storage/9-initialize-the-storage-account-model?pivots=javascript to connect an application to the Azure Storage account.

At step 8, when I verify the creation of the container by running the given Azure CLI command and replacing  with my storage account:

```
az storage container list \
--account-name <name>
```

I get the following output:

```
There are no credentials provided in your command and environment, we will query for account key for your storage account.
It is recommended to provide --connection-string, --account-key or --sas-token in your command as credentials.

You also can add `--auth-mode login` in your command to use Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) for authorization if your login account is assigned required RBAC roles.
For more information about RBAC roles in storage, visit https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-rbac-cli.

In addition, setting the corresponding environment variables can avoid inputting credentials in your command. Please use --help to get more information about environment variable usage.
[]
```

which I am not sure whether the container is listed as [] at the end of the above output.

Comments and suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- This error you are getting is because of an auth issue.
- So, there are three solution one is that you run the following command before the running the  `az storage container list`

```
az login
```

- The other way would be to use the `--auth-mode` option in the `az storage container list`   this is written in the error prompt itself which you have given.

command:

```
az storage container list --account-name <name> --auth-mode login
```

this will prompt you for login credentials once provided the output should look like this

[image]

- Lastly you can use the same option as above but with key

```
az storage container list --account-name <name> --auth-mode key <key>
```

you can get your key from the portal under access keys

[image]

The output of the command should look like this here I have two containers name photos and test.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**I tried to reproduce in my environment and I got same error:**

[image]

> There are no credentials provided in your command and environment,
> we will query for account key for your storage account. It is
> recommended to provide --connection-string, --account-key or
> --sas-token in your command as credentials.
>
> You also can add `--auth-mode login` in your command to use Azure
> Active Directory (Azure AD) for authorization if your login account is
> assigned required RBAC roles. For more information about RBAC roles in
> storage, visit
> https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-rbac-cli.
>
> In addition, setting the corresponding environment variables can avoid
> inputting credentials in your command. Please use --help to get more
> information about environment variable usage. []

The above error show that in your storage account you didn't create any containers and files.

I have created one container and add files.

[image]

[image]

I tried the same command now i got an output successfully.

[image]

If you need to remove warnings you can use this command`--only-show-errors`

[image]

***Reference:***
[az storage container | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-container-list)